# how to shift array value in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, array

we want to build 6 mount point folders as example

```
/data/sdb
/data/sdc
/data/sdd
/data/sde
/data/sdf
/data/sdg
```

so we wrote this simple bash script using array

```
folder_mount_point_list="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg"

folderArray=( $folder_mount_point_list )

counter=0
for i in disk1 disk2 disk3 disk4 disk4 disk5 disk6
do
folder_name=${folderArray[counter]}
mkdir /data/$folder_name
let counter=$counter+1
done
```

now we want to change the code without **counter** and **let=$counter=counter+1**

is it possible to shift each loop the array in order to get the next array value?

as something like

```
${folderArray[++]}
```

Comment: what's `for i in disk1 disk2 disk3 disk4 disk4 disk5 disk6` for as it's not being used within loop body?

Comment: ... and what is the point of using a counter ? Why don't you simply run `for  i in "your_list_goes_here"; do mkdir /data/"$i"; done` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A general remark. It does not make sense to define an array like this:

```
folder_mount_point_list="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg"
folderArray=( $folder_mount_point_list )
```

You would do this instead:

```
folderArray=(sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg)
```

Now to your question:

```
set -- sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg
for folder_name; do
    mkdir "/data/$folder_name"
done
```

or

```
set -- sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    mkdir "/data/$1"
    shift
done
```

Comment: can we do the set for variable as  set -- $list_of_folders ( while list_of_folders="sdb sdc sdd sde"

Comment: @yael Yes, you can use `set -- $list_of_folders` but again: String variables are not the way to go: `set -- "${folders[@]}"`

Comment: why are you even using `set -- ....`?  that hack is only needed in shells that don't support arrays - there's no need for it in a shell that does supports arrays.   `for folder_name in "${folderArray[@]}"; do ... ; done` is all that's needed.

Comment: just one question , is there any choice to do something like - ${folderArray[++]}

Comment: @cas that's what I have in my answer. I don't get this `set` approach either.

Comment: @cas The OP explicitly asked for "shift". But `shift` works with positional parameters only. Of course, maybe I misunderstood the OP by taking that expression literally.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I think OP just wanted to get rid of the counter while preserving the same functionality. That doesn't necessarily mean OP wants to shift the array. I think it's just an unlucky phrasing :)

Answer (score 32):

To answer the question in the title, you can "shift" an array with the substring/subarray notation. `shift` itself works with just the positional parameters.

```
$ a=(a b c d e)
$ a=("${a[@]:1}")
$ echo "${a[@]}"
b c d e
```

Similarly, to 'pop' the last item off the array: `a=("${a[@]:0:${#a[@]} - 1}" )` or `unset "a[${#a[@]}-1]"`

So if you wanted to, you could do this:

```
a=(foo bar doo)
b=(123 456 789)
while [ "${#a[@]}" -gt 0 ]; do
    echo "$a $b"
    a=("${a[@]:1}")
    b=("${b[@]:1}")
done
```

But it trashes the arrays, and the "shifting" assignments probably copy the data around unnecessarily, so **just indexing as usual might be better**.

```
a=(foo bar doo)
b=(123 456 789)
i=0
while [ "$i" -lt "${#a[@]}" ]; do
    echo "${a[i]} ${b[i]}"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Or maybe use an associative array instead, if you don't care about the order of the items. `"${!arr[@]}"` gives the keys in an unspecified order, probably *not* the order they were assigned in:

```
declare -A arr=([foo]=123 [bar]=456 [doo]=789)
for k in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$k ${arr[$k]}"
done
```

Comment: Strictly speaking you are not *shifting* the array, but re-assigning it to a subset of itself. For large arrays that may be inefficient.

Comment: @U.Windl, that's probably why the "shift" there is in quotes. And the answer does say that indexing as usual might be better... But since there's no operation to directly shift an array in the shell (it's not Perl), that's what you can do. If you have a large dataset and care about performance, you probably shouldn't use the shell to begin with.

Comment: Well there's "almost" a shift operator. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/648243/320598

Comment: @U.Windl, as you noticed, it doesn't shift the indexes, just removes one of them. The only point for shifting I can see is to be able to point to the first element using an unchanging index. With the positional parameters, you can do that, since after a `shift`, the new first arg is `$1`. Similarly `shift @a` in Perl makes `$a[0]` the new first element of the array. But that doesn't work with `unset "x[0]"`, you still need to keep track of the index of the element you want to access, and then you don't even need the "shifting". So, **just indexing as usual might be better.**

Comment: Instead of `i=0; while [ "$i" -lt "${#a[@]}" ]; do` it would be simpler and probably faster to do `for i in {0..$((${#a[@]}-1))}; do`.

Comment: @SteffenHeil, maybe. The problem is that it pretty much only works in ksh as Bash does brace expansion _before_ variable expansion (rather a useless order, IMO, but here we are). `{1..${#a[@]}}` works in zsh, though, and one could use `"${!a[@]}"` also with a regular array (in Bash and ksh).

Answer (score 4):

You can simply loop over all values, no shifting needed:

```
folderArray=(sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg)

for folder in "${folderArray[@]}"; do
    mkdir "/data/$folder"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any loop for that:

```
folderArray=(sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg)
IFS=,
eval mkdir /data/{"${folderArray[*]}"}
```

The trick is that if an array is double-quoted with subscript `*` (`"${array[*]}"`) it expands to a single word with the value of each array element separated by the first character of the `IFS` variable. After that we use brace expansion mechanism to attach `/data/` to each array member and `eval`uate the whole thing.

Comment: Why so complicated? `cd /data ; mkdir "${folderArray[@]}"` I have done the same before but I would not in a case like this. But +1 for the advanced approach.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Yes, that would be simpler in case of `mkdir` command. And and even array is not needed, just `cd /data; mkdir abc def` as normal person would do. But could not be as simple for other tasks, so it is good to know how to quickly attach a string to each array element without a loop.

Comment: just one question , is there any choice to do something like - ${folderArray[++]}

Comment: @yael You can do something like `echo "${folderArray[((counter++))]}"` if you really like this approach. Stuff inside `(())` is evaluated as math (notice lack of `$` in front of `counter`).

Comment: and when you start writing shell code like that, you realise that putting a little time into learning perl or python would be a good idea.  i.e. just because you *can* do something with bash, doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking is how to use `++` to increment an array index.

Like this:

```
folderArray=( sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg  )

counter=0

for i in disk1 disk2 disk3 disk4 disk5 disk6; do
    folder_name=${folderArray[counter++]}
    echo mkdir /data/$folder_name
done
```

The index of an array (what's inside the `[]`) is in an Arithmetic environment, so the post increment (`++`) work.

---

The question on the title use the term `shift`. Shifting like the positional arguments could be done by re-building the array (a slow process).

```
folderArray=( sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg  )

shiftArray=( "${folderArray[@]}" )

counter=0
for i in disk1 disk2 disk3 disk4 disk5 disk6; do
    echo mkdir /data/$shiftArray

    shiftArray=( "${shiftArray[@]:1}" )

done
```

---

But it seems simpler to use the array indexes directly:

```
folderArray=( sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg  )

for((i=0;i<${#folderArray[@]};)); do
    echo mkdir /data/"${folderArray[i++]}"
done
```